# Using the data property in Angular 2 router - inconsistent behaviour

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using the data property of a route to provide breadcrumbs in my app. I have two child modules with very similar routing components. Both have top-level routes with children, and one of them has further child routes at a lower level.

There are two distinct cases for extracting a breadcrumb token. One is where the breadcrumb is a static part of the route, and the second is where the breadcrumb is defined as part of the object being displayed.

In the first case, I need to use the value defined in the route, and in the second I do not want a breadcrumb token defined in the route because it comes from somewhere else.

With one module I get exactly the behaviour I want: I declare a data property value at the top level of the route hierarchy, and in the ActivatedRouteSnapshot it only appears at that level. In the second module, the data property value declared at the top level also appears in the child nodes of the ActivatedRouteSnapshot.

Any help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Code samples and ActivatedRouteSnapshot instances are shown below.

Thanks!

**Module 1: Projects**

```
const projectRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'projects',
    component: ProjectsComponent,
    data: {breadcrumb: 'Projects'},
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {path: '', component: ProjectListComponent},
        {path: ':projectId', component: ProjectComponent, 
            resolve: {project: ProjectResolve, StaticDataResolve},
            children: [
                {path: ':datafileGroupId/upload', 
                    component: DatafileUploadComponent, 
                    data: {breadcrumb: 'Upload'},
                    resolve: {staticData: StaticDataResolve}},
                {path: ':datafileId', 
                    resolve: {datafile: DatafileResolve, 
                              staticData: StaticDataResolve},
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: 'derive',
                            component: DatafileDeriveComponent,
                            data: {breadcrumb: 'Derive'}
                        },
                        {path: '', component: DatafileComponent}
                    ]
                },
                {path: '', component: ProjectDetailComponent }
            ]
        },
        {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login'},
    ]
}
];
```

In the Projects module, the breadcrumb token 'Projects' is assigned to the top-level route's data property. Some child routes have their own breadcrumb tokens which work with no problem. The child route for a particular project (`path: ':projectId'`) in particular has no data property. In that case, my breadcrumb component extracts the value to use from the project instance.

Here is the ActivatedRouteSnapshot for the Projects module. The 'Projects' token assigned to the data property of the top-level route shows up at the top level but not lower down.

```
ActivatedRouteSnapshot
    _lastPathIndex: 0
    _resolve: Object
    _resolvedData: Object
    _routeConfig: Object
    _routerState: RouterStateSnapshot
    _urlSegment: UrlSegmentGroup
    children: Array[1]
        0: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
            _lastPathIndex: 1
            _resolve: Object
            _resolvedData: Object
            _routeConfig: Object
            _routerState: RouterStateSnapshot
            _urlSegment: UrlSegmentGroup
            children: (...)
            component: ProjectComponent(route)
            data: Object                    <==== No breadcrumb token
                StaticDataResolve: Object
                project: Object
                __proto__: Object
            firstChild: (...)
            fragment: undefined
            outlet: "primary"
            params: Object
            parent: (...)
            pathFromRoot: (...)
            queryParams: Object
            root: (...)
            routeConfig: (...)
            url: Array[1]
        __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
    component: ProjectsComponent()
    data: Object
        breadcrumb: "Projects"      <==== breadcrumb token appears correctly
        __proto__: Object
    firstChild: (...)
    -- truncated --
```

**Module 2: Calculations**

```
const calculationRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'calculations',
        component: CalculationsComponent,
        resolve: {staticData: StaticDataResolve},
        data: {breadcrumb: 'Calculations'},
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {path: '', component: CalculationListComponent},
            {path: 'new',
                component: CalculationComponent,
                data: {breadcrumb: 'New'}},
            {path: ':calculationId',
                component: CalculationComponent,
                resolve: {calculation: CalculationResolve}},
            {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login'},
        ]
    }
];
```

The setup for the Calculations module is very similar. In particular, the top-level breadcrumb token is set in the same way and the child route for a particular calculation (`path: ':calculationId'`) has no data property.

Here is the ActivatedRouteSnapshot showing the breadcrumb token appearing incorrectly on the child routes:

```
ActivatedRouteSnapshot
    _lastPathIndex : 0 
    _resolve : Object
    _resolvedData : Object
    _routeConfig : Object
    _routerState : RouterStateSnapshot
    _urlSegment : UrlSegmentGroup
    children : Array[1]
        0 : ActivatedRouteSnapshot
            _lastPathIndex : 1 
            _resolve : Object
            _resolvedData : Object
            _routeConfig : Object
            _routerState : RouterStateSnapshot
            _urlSegment : UrlSegmentGroup
            children : (...)
            component : CalculationComponent(route, router, menuService, dataService, snackBar, dialog, utils)
            data : Object
                breadcrumb : "Calculations"  <==== Unwanted breadcrumb token
                calculation : Object
                staticData : Object
                __proto__ : Object
            firstChild : (...)
            fragment : undefined
            outlet : "primary"
            params : Object
            parent : (...)
            pathFromRoot : (...)
            queryParams : Object
            root : (...)
            routeConfig : (...)
            url : Array[1]
            __proto__ : Object
        length : 1 
    __proto__ : Array[0]
    component : undefined
    data : Object
        breadcrumb : "Calculations"    <==== Breadcrumb token shown correctly
        staticData : Object
        __proto__ : Object
    firstChild : (...)
    --- truncated ---
```